# Pandas: how to join back your data after a operation

Tags: python, pandas, merge, scikit-learn

I have the following dataframe

```
df:

group people value value_50
  1    5      100    1
  2    2      90     1
  1    10     80     1
  2    20     40     0
  1    7      10     0
  2    23     30     0
```

And I am trying to apply sklearn minmax on one of the column, given a condition on dataset, and then want to join that back as per pandas index in my original data

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

After copying the above data

```
data = pd.read_clipboard()
minmax  = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,10))

''' Applying a filter on "group" and then apply minmax only on those values '''

val = pd.DataFrame(minmax.fit_transform(data[data['group'] == 1][['value']])
                     ,columns = ['val_minmax'] )
```

But it looks like we lose the index after the minmax

```
  val
  val_minmax
0   10.000000
1   7.777778
2   0.000000
```

where index in my original dataset on this filter is

```
data[data['group'] == 1]['value']

   output:
 0    100
 2     80
 4     10
```

Desired dataset:

```
   df_out: 

   group people value value_50 val_minmax
      1    5    100    1        10
      2    2    90     1        na
      1    10   80     1        7.88
      2    20   40     0        na
      1    7    10     0        0
      2    23   30     0        na
```

Now, how to join back my data at rows in the original data, so that I can get the above output?

Comment: Is the third value in `val_minmax` supposed to be `80`? And not `7.777778`?

Comment: Could you explain a little better your expected output ?

Comment: Now edited the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to assign it back

```
df.loc[df.group==1,'val_minmax']=minmax.fit_transform(df[df['group'] == 1][['value']])
```

Comment: @jezrael what you mean the expected  output not match ?